# UWP: PivotItem Header with count

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, windows-10-universal, uwp-xaml

I have a pivot that creates the items from a list.
Now I want to show a count in the Heading-Text 
For example when I have a list of 5 items, I want in the header following text:
Item1, Item2, Item3 ...

This is the code of my Pivot:

```
 <Pivot ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentItem, Mode=TwoWay}" SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedIndex, Mode=TwoWay}">
        <Pivot.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
               <!-- Data-->
            </DataTemplate>
        </Pivot.ItemTemplate>
    </Pivot>
```

Any ideas??

Comment: Maybe you can put a property inside your item class, responsible for header tiltle and then bind to it? If you have such property it should be easy to update it with list numbers.

Comment: Thx.. 
first I tried it this way and it didn't worked, but the problem was not my idea.. the problem was the Data-Binding with the property ItemsSource...

I forgot the Element-Name by the DataBinding from the top element...

Comment: What do you mean about forgetting the Element-Name by the DataBing from the top element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe inside `<DataTemplate>` to create a `PivotItem` with

```
Header="{Binding YOURITEM}">
```